# Returning a pandas column sorted based upon the total unique values in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to solve the following issue.

I need to return the top 10 results from column A, based upon the highest total of unique results from column B.

```
df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'])['Col2'].unique().sort_values().count()
```

This is what I came up with and it returns just the total count of unique values, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Input
Col1             Col2
Sam Jones        Broken Toe
Rebecca Stevens  Broken Arm
Sam Jones        Broken Foot

output

Sam Jones - 2
Rebecca Stevens -1

Comment: a minimal input/output example would make your goal more explicit ;)

Comment: Input
Col1             Col2
Sam Jones  Broken Toe
Rebecca Stevens  Broken Arm
Sam Jones Broken Foot

output

Sam Jones - 2
Rebecca Stevens -1

Comment: I think that's not what @mozway meant by that. You need to provide at least a table, better provide a data frame within the code environment. If you do not know how to do that, then have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) post to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Col1': {0: 'Sam Jones', 1: 'Rebecca Stevens', 2: 'Sam Jones'},
                             'Col2': {0: 'Broken Toe', 1: 'Broken Arm', 2: 'Broken Foot'}})

df.groupby(['Col1']).agg('nunique').sort_values(by='Col2', ascending=False)[:10]
```